# high contrast theme not showing uncreated wikilinks -- how do i fix this in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

I use dendron an extension that creates wikilinks in vscode.

when i choose high contrast theme, the color of the uncreated note (as in the note is not yet created for that wikilink) becomes too dark.

[image]

when i choose dark theme, the color of the uncreated note link is an orange which is visible.

[image]

I found this https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color which talks about all the possible settings. but i cannot identify which one this is for.

Can advise?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) by running the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command to find out VS code's internal token name for the uncreated note:

[image]

[image]

Then use the identified token to set a certain color for it in your JSON settings:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "support.type.property-name",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#65a9b9"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
}
```